# REMOVE_TASK_KILL_PROCESS cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, github, pull

I'm having a problem where I pulled a [repo from GitHub](https://github.com/EatHeat/OmniSnitch), and I am getting an error which I'm unsure how to fix.

The error is `REMOVE_TASK_KILL_PROCESS cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. If this didnt actually exist, wouldn't the original author not be able to compile it?

The actual line of code is:

```
        am.removeTask(ad.getPersistentTaskId(),
                ActivityManager.REMOVE_TASK_KILL_PROCESS);
```

"am" is a ActivityManager variable and "ad" is a custom object.